# Unresolved external symbol NtCreateKey

Tags: c++

I am trying to create registry key using WINAPI NtCreateKey but I am getting this error in VS2013.

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `"long __stdcall NtCreateKey(void **, unsigned long, struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *, unsigned long, struct _UNICODE_STRING *, unsigned long, unsigned long *)"`
>   (?NtCreateKey@@YGJPAPAXKPAU_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES@@KPAU_UNICODE_STRING@@KPAK@Z) referenced in function _main

Anyone has any idea why. I have also included the following files:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you link the dll where the `NtCreateKey` implementation is?

Comment: Yes...I have linked the ntdll.lib.

Comment: how did you load the function? Did you use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`

Comment: Use the documented api, RegCreateKeyEx().

Comment: Thanks for the help, it appears that I have linked the wrong ntdll.lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dynamically resolve NtCreateKey by using LoadLibrary to get a handle to ntdll, and the use GetProcAddress to resolve the function.

Conversely, you could use the supported Win32 API function RegCreateKey/RegCreateKeyEx. Unless you have a real reason to use the native API, you should probably stick to the Win32 API.